# Delete a row by SQLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to write a Query to delete a row from the table. I have confused of writing the statement. I need some help in revising this.

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id="+id, null);
```

I get my id from editText then put it into String id.
This is the way to get my id:

```
String id = editId.getText().toString();
```

If there's not enough information to make you understand my problem, please tell me. I will add lacking parts.

I have find many data but I still cannot revise it. I would be thankful for your help.

This is my onCreate function:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String INIT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                                  _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                  NAME + " CHAR, " +
                                  TEL + " CHAR, " +
                                  EMAIL + " CHAR);"; 
        db.execSQL(INIT_TABLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said **"I want to write a Query to delete a row from the table."**

```
  private void deleteRow(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL("delete from tablename where tablefield=" +id);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

you can call this function and pass id in it to delete row.

Comment: Good to know. How? you can share your knowledge :)

Comment: Mmm... It's my fault. Im sorry to post this question. Because i learn SQLite first time, this is a sample project I found. However, I misunderstand the input, so I enter a name into the ID Column. Then, it went wrong. but i still thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me see the syntax below:

```
String table = "TableName";
String where = "ColumnNumeric = 100"
    + " AND ColumnString = 'value2'";
String whereArgs = null;
mDb.delete(table, where, whereArgs);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I use this way it would work, but the row wouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Any Error? what is the type of your Id column?

Comment: I have added my onCreate function. My Id column is _ID which is declared by android.provider.BaseColumns;.

Comment: In the light of code you provided, the deletion should work!! i can't find nothing wrong!!

Comment: It's my fault. Im sorry to post this question. Because i learn SQLite first time, this is a sample project I found. However, I misunderstand the input, so I enter a name into the ID Column. Then, it went wrong. but i still thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void delete_byID(int id){
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
    }
```